# Firebird2.5 Error: "duplicate value in unique index" without duplicate data

Tags: sql, database, sql-insert, firebird2.5, ibexpert

Hello and thanks for reading and probably also helping me

brief explanation of my problem:

I am copying Data from one Firebird-Database to another (called V14) and i am using IBExpert to do so.
The tables are named equally and have the same structure. For the purpose of explaining i am going to call the table containing the data in the old database A and the table i want to insert the data into shall be called B.

So the only thing to do is to take all Data from table A and insert them into table B.
The small piece of Code to do so is:

```
INSERT into [V14].BSMZ SELECT * FROM BSMZ
```

executing this i receive the error-Message (after some rows were transfered):

Invalid insert or update value(s): object columns are constrained - no 2 table rows can have duplicate column values. attempt to store duplicate value (visible to active transactions) in unique index "UI_BSMZ"

This unique-Index contains 2 Data-colums and applies to table B and A.

There are multiple rows that cause this problem but also multiple rows are transfered as desired.
I have prooved that the rows, that can't be inserted into table B have values in their unique-key-colums, that are not alredy present in table B.

(For purpose of testing i did remove the constraint from table B. But i still get the same error-message, wich confuses me even more)

I am not really sure what could cause this problem and would appreciate some hints.

Comment: In some cases it might occur with a corrupt index that backs the unique constraint. Also check that there are no null values in one of the constrained columns.

Comment: There are no null-Values in the constrained colums. Maybe i should ask google how to fix a corrupt index and take a look if this solves the issue...

Comment: Another thing: does the constraint include (var)char columns? If so, could it be a column with a case insensitive and/or accent insensitive collation?

Comment: It contains an integer and a VarChar(6) colum. But the VarChar is only used to store numbers. (dont ask me why, i did not design it - i just have to cope with it ^^)

Answer (score 1):

you got exactly error info unique index "UI_BSMZ"
find this declaration of unique constraint - it is not about foreign key from B to A
this is constraint in table on some field[s]

in source database run query on fields from this UK UI_BSMZ

```
SELECT UK_FIELD_1, UK_FIELD_2, .. FROM TABLE_NAME GROUP BY UK_FIELD_1, UK_FIELD_2, .. HAVING     COUNT(*)>1 PLAN (TABLE_NAME NATURAL)
```

if this query return some rows - than in source database index is corrupted  - or not exists

to fix index (after deleting duplicates) - run this:

```
Alter Index INDEX_NAME ACTIVE;
```

this rebuild your index

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem: after copying data I couldn't insert new row into the table. Turned out it was related to ID generator.
So I simply found generator in database, and increased value of ID to bigger, then maximum ID value in the table.